# Determining number of records inserted when using Zzz Entity Framework Extensions and BulkInsert

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to know how many records were inserted when using Zzz Entity Framework Extensions and [BulkInsert](https://entityframework-extensions.net/bulk-insert)?

Example code:

```cs
                using StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
                using JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
                IEnumerable<TDataType> data = loader.LoadJson(jsonReader);

                // DB options
                // TODO : Add MySql support
                DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TelemetryDbContext>();
                optionsBuilder
                    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));
                    //.UseMySql(connectionString, providerOptions => providerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));

                // Open DB connection
                using TelemetryDbContext dbContext = new TelemetryDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

                // Make sure DB schema is created
                dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

                // Bulk insert data
                dbContext.BulkInsert(data, 
                    options => 
                    { 
                        options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
                        options.AllowDuplicateKeys = true;
                    });

                // TODO: How many records were inserted?
```

Comment: `data.Count()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to get the row affected with the option `UseRowsAffected` (will make the bulk operation slightly slower.

```
var resultInfo = new Z.BulkOperations.ResultInfo();

ctx.BulkInsert(list, options =>
{
 options.UseRowsAffected = true;
 options.ResultInfo = resultInfo;
 ;
});

var rowsAffected = resultInfo.RowsAffected;
```

Online Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HuPnly

Comment: what is "slightly" mean?  how much slower?